# Error 13 de Visual Basic, no puede ejecutar el codigo

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, bucle-for, formulas

Es una simple sumatoria con una formula larga.
Me dice que no coinciden los datos (error 13).
Dice que el error esta en la fórmula.
Adjunto foto de la fórmula y codigo.

Nota: Los valores de entrada son 'x' y 't' por eso no tienen valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Sub Sumatoria()
Dim PI As Double
Dim K_EULER As Double
Dim L As Double
Dim n As Double
Dim Alfa As Double
Dim S As Double
Dim Sumatoria As Double
Dim x As Double
Dim t As Double
PI = 3.14159265358979
K_EULER = 0.577215664901532
L = 0.02
Alfa = 0.000001
S = 0
For n = 1 To 1000
S = S + (4 / PI) * [[((-1)^(n-1))/(2*n-1)]*cos[((2*n-1)*PI*x)/(2*L)]*(K_EULER)^[[[((2*n-1)*PI)/2*L]^2]*-Alfa*t]]
Next n
Sumatoria = S
End Sub
```

Comment: Sustituye todos los corchetes por paréntesis.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia los corchetes por paréntesis.

Si es VB.Net, cambia la función Cos por Math.Cos

```
Public Sub Sumatoria()
    Dim PI As Double
    Dim K_EULER As Double
    Dim L As Double
    Dim n As Double
    Dim Alfa As Double
    Dim S As Double
    Dim Sumatoria As Double
    Dim x As Double
    Dim t As Double
    PI = 3.14159265358979
    K_EULER = 0.577215664901532
    L = 0.02
    Alfa = 0.000001
    S = 0
    For n = 1 To 1000
        S += (4 / PI) * ((((-1) ^ (n - 1)) / (2 * n - 1)) * Math.Cos(((2 * n - 1) * PI * x) / (2 * L)) * (K_EULER) ^ (((((2 * n - 1) * PI) / 2 * L) ^ 2) * -Alfa * t))

    Next n
    Sumatoria = S
End Sub
```